# why different packages or naming conventions in google cloud?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk

I have recently started using google cloud platform and came across various packages like

```
Storage storage = storageBilder.build();
storage.get("bucketname", Storage.BucketGetOption.fields())
Storage.BucketGetOption.fields();
```

If I use the code above i am  facing `The method get(String, Storage.BucketGetOption) is undefined for the type Storage`.

It actually using the storage from below packages

```
com.google.api.services.storage.Storage storage = storageBilder.build();
(i.still.do.not.know.this.)storage.get("bucketname", Storage.BucketGetOption.fields())
com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.BucketGetOption.fields();
```

why this storage is implemented in  various ways? what is the difference or use of `com.google.api` and `com.google.cloud`?

Could anybody please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Google has released a number of Java API client libraries over the years.

The current, best Java API client is the [google-cloud library](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java). It uses the Java packages `com.google.cloud`. For Cloud Storage, you're using this library if the classes are under `com.google.cloud.storage`.

Before this library, there was another set of libraries called the [Google APIs Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries). These libraries put their classes in the `com.google.api` package. For Cloud Storage, you'd find classes in `com.google.api.services.storage`. Code that uses this library will also use a distinctive storage-resource-verb function pattern, like `storage.buckets().objects().get()` pattern.

The Google APIs Client Libraries are still supported, but I recommend preferring the google-cloud libraries for new code. Unfortunately, because of this library switch-over, some code examples you'll find online will use the former or the latter or, worse, both.